# Reload Total section in checkout/cart page - Matgento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento-2.1.3, totals

I want to reload total section when checkbox checked/unchecked.

[image]

Here is the code I am trying to implement.

`etc/frontend/sections.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="extrafee/update/updatesession">
        <section name="cart"/>
    </action>
</config>
```

Trying to call the line in my `phtml` file.

```
<script>
    require(['jquery'], function ($) {
        $("#installation").change(function() {
            require('Magento_Customer/js/customer-data').reload(['checkout-data'], false)
        });
    });
</script>
```

If I reload page manually, it is okay. the total is updating.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
<section name="checkout-data"/>
```

to your sections.xml
like this

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="extrafee/update/updatesession">
        <section name="cart"/>
        <section name="checkout-data"/>
    </action>
</config>
```

and also request your action when you checked/unchecked

```
<script>
    require(['jquery'], function ($) {
        $("#installation").change(function() {
            var url = "<?php echo $this->getUrl('extrafee/update/updatesession', array('_secure'=>true)) ?>";
            $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: {checked:your_value_here},
            showLoader: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){
                console.log("success");
            }
        });

        });
    });
</script>
```

**Don't forget to replace (your_value_here) with your checkbox value** in this line

```
data: {checked:your_value_here},
```

Comment: I want to reload it after success my ajax call. b'coz here  extrafee/update/updatesession I have some logic to implement fee on cart. So after calculation, i want to reload cart total